# Inconsistent appearance of square root sign in plot labels

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling, labeled, appearance

Observe the inconsistency in the appearance of the title on the following plots:

```
label = "\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(Test\)]\)"

Plot[{t, t^2}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> label]

Plot[{t, t^2}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> label, 
  PlotLegends -> ""]

Plot[{t, t^2}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> label, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, 
    {Right, Center}]]
```

The output of "label" and the title of the second `Plot` entry appear as

[image]

but the titles of the first and third `Plot` entries appear as

[image]

What's going on here, and how can I consistently produce the first (smaller) appearance in plot titles regardless of the `PlotLegend` setting? The trick of using the dummy setting `PlotLegends->""` will not work because I am trying to place a legend inside my plot image, as in the third entry.

---

Incidentally, this issue only seems to arise when capital letters are used inside the square root sign. If "Test" is replaced with "test", for example, the issue vanishes. But alas, I need to place a combination of lowercase and uppercase letters under the square root sign in my application.

---

EDIT:

There was an answer (now deleted, for some reason) suggesting

```
Plot[{t, t^2}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> 
     {Placed[label, 
         {Top, Center}], Placed[Automatic, 
         {Right, Center}]}]
```

This works except that now "Test" is formatted with a different style from typical `PlotLabel`. It is formatted with the same style as the output of `label`, which is different from that of `PlotLabel`, as pointed out by Michael E2 in the comments.

To see the difference observe the output of

```
Plot[{t, t^2}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> label, 
   PlotLegends -> 
     {Placed[label, 
         {Top, Center}], ""}]
```

[image]

---

Incidentally, I have found another solution that seems to work:

```
Labeled[Plot[{t, t^2}, {t, 0, 1}, 
     PlotLabel -> label], ""]
```

Still, seems hacky and it would be nice to understand what's going on with the different display styles.

---

EDIT 2:

The workaround I proposed just above actually isn't ideal because when I save as PDF, the blank label creates extra space under the plot image. Also, as an added wrinkle, even when using this trick, right-clicking the image and then choosing "Save Graphic As..." and saving as a PDF reverts the label to the "bad" form with too much space inside the square root sign! After selecting the whole cell, right-clicking and choosing "Save Selection As..." and saving as a PDF, the square root prints properly but the blank space is added at the bottom. What a mess!

Comment: I'm curious if there's a WL equivalent for $\TeX$'s \vphantom.  As a way to perhaps force all roots to conform to the tallest character.

Comment: The output of `label` is typeset with a different style than in `Plot`. My plots all have the same look (V12.2, Mac). -- The output of `Style[label, "Graphics", Larger]` seems to match my plots.

Comment: I have V12.0 Mac, so maybe the upgrade fixes the issue, though I'm not sure I have access to V12.2.

Comment: My plots also all have the same look (v12.2 on Windows 10), so probably this was fixed. Also, I suggest using the `MaTeX` package for nicer-looking and perfectly uniform labels...

Comment: @FidelI.Schaposnik I just updated to 12.2 and that fixed the problem. So I guess the best solution was the simplest after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon my tests and the comments to the original question, it appears that this problem does not occur in Mathematica 12.2.  The recommended solution is therefore to upgrade.